# Blocking Locks versus Non-Blocking Locks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrent-programming

I am thinking here: If you have 2 threads executing FAST operations that need to be synchronized, isn't a nonblocking approach faster/better than a blocking/context switch approach?

By non-blocking I mean something like:

while(true) {
    if (checkAndGetTheLock()) break;
  }

The only thing I can think of is starvation (with CPU burn out) if you have too many threads looping around the lock.

How do I balance one approach versus the other?

Comment: How many lock operations will you be doing per CPU core per second?

Comment: AFAIK, the JVM does this optimization for you if there is no contention on the lock (which should be the case if the operation is fast)

Comment: @JB Nizet: I think you have to make that decision yourself by using synchronized versus ReentrantLock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what *Java Concurrency in Practice* says about the subject:

> The JVM can implement blocking either via spin-waiting (repeatedly
>   trying to acquire the lock until it succeeds) or bysuspending the
>   blocked thread through the operating system. Which is more efficient
>   depends on the relationship between context switch overhead and the
>   time until the lock becomes available; spin-waiting is preferable for
>   short waits and suspension is preferable for long waits. Some JVMs
>   choose between the two adaptively based on profiling data of past wait
>   times, but most just suspend threads waiting for a lock.

And also (which is, IMO, the most important point):

> Don't worry excessively about the cost of uncontended synchronization.
>   The basic mechanism is already quite fast, and JVMs can perform
>   additional optimizations that further reduce or eliminate the cost.
>   Instead, focus optimization efforts on areas where lock contention
>   actually occurs.

Comment: I would not trust that "Some JVMs choose between the two adaptively based on profiling data of past wait times, but most just suspend threads waiting for a lock." But you can never know what those modern hotspot JVMs are capable of. I would think that synchronized is blocking and ReentrantLock is busy-waiting. But if they can change into each other at runtime I am not sure.

Comment: Where have you read that ReentrantLock is busy-waiting? If it did, it would bring the JVM to its knees for long waits. The javadoc says: *A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.*

Comment: I can be wrong, but by browsing the source code i thought it was its approach: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer-source.html NOOOOO! The JVM does NOT use ReentrantLock for its internal things.

Comment: @chrisapotek The ReentrantLock is built using the AbstractQueuedSynchronizer as a synchronization mechanism.  In other words the ReentrantLock uses the AbstractQueuedSynchronizer to suspend and awake threads.  But as JB Nizet noted, ReentrantLock is absolutely a blocking construct

Comment: So if I want to use a busy waiting lock I have to do it myself using the atomic primitives, right?

Comment: @chrisapotek Yes, you can write a a simple Mutex using an AtomicBoolean. `while(!flag.compareAndSet(false,true));` would be a busy-spin lock acquire.

Answer (score 2):

Well the only way to be sure is test it. When it comes to multithreading and performance you simply can't assume.

Comment: @usr well, why did you not upvote it then?  I was sorely tempted to downvote it twice, but that would be unfair on M Platvoet.

Comment: @usr - in that case, I'll add an upvote too, because it is the only way to be sure.  Testing is important, but before a developer gets to that stage, there are some designs that will definitely result in abysmal performance, no assumptions needed.  Not using them is a matter of training/experience.